# What's the recommended way of using global data on Android?

Tags: android, design-patterns, architecture

Let's say we develop an app with web authorisation. We need some "global" service to determine whether the user is logged. If user is logged, the service must provide some data (such as cookies, auth token, etc) to identity user, otherwise the service must have a way to set this data.

There are couple of ways of doing it. We can use static context (singleton or just static fields) to store this data. We also may create some Service to get all this data from.

But what way is recommended by Google? What way is ideologically correct? Perhaps there are other ways to implement that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create manager (singleton pattern) that describes your app model. Yes, make sure also that it does not hold context of Activity, Service and etc. If need context, make sure to call [getApplicationContext()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext()).

Comment: I'm using that way right now, but this is easiest way. I'm trying to avoid using globals, I looking for the new design(Android-specs) pattern.
For example, a Service -- but Service binding creates some overhead to use it on each screen.

Comment: I was at google IO 2014, I asked question about how to share data across components of the app. Android team said that singleton is just fine, they do it inside framework all over. So I do not see why not, since it is simple and clean.

Comment: Sad, but true. I've hoped the is some alternative(some kind of AOP or сross-cutting concern), but if Googlers using singletons, I'm surrender.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what's recommended by Google but if you need an object that lives as long as your application lives then it would be the `Application` object.

So subclass your own `MyApplication` `extends Application`, define whatever fields you need in there and then declare `MyApplication` in manifest and access by `(MyApplication)getApplication()`

Comment: This is just an another kind of singleton, and this is lazy way. I'm trying to avoid using globals, I looking for the new design pattern.

Comment: There are no new design patterns. This is a singleton already existing for you.

Answer (score 0):

Singelton is the simplest way doing it (+design pattern)

But from time to time, there may be problems using singeltons: if the application process is killed, which will happen almost undoubtedly if you leave the app in the background too long, your singleton will be recreated, and so your private int data will be reset to a default value.

Maybe if you don't want to use too much shared data you can use sharedpreferences to avoid this.

Else you could try Extending the Application class.

Hope helps